# JQuery: Trying to execute function after each, not working

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have a massive each loop, and each iteration makes an ajax request:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    $.ajax(function() {...})
    .done(function { ... });
}
```

After executing every iteration, I want to execute another function that alerts. To do this, I tried using promise()

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    ...
}).promise().done(function () {alert("This is an alert");});
```

However, that doesn't work: the alert executes before the each loop is finished. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the alert within the ajax so you know it finished loading the code. Do this...

```
var totalCount=$('#test').length;
var ajaxCounter=0;
$('#test').each(function() {
    $.ajax(function() {

        //do stuff here


    })
    .done(function { 
        //do other stuff here


        ajaxCounter++;
        if(ajaxCounter==totalCount){
            alert('this is an alert at the end');
        }

    });
}
```

If there is a chance that some of the ajax calls won't fire you might also want to use a setTimer to set off the alert if too much time passes... or just use the deferred fail method to keep track of them like this:

```
var totalCount=$('#test').length;
var ajaxCounter=0;
$('#test').each(function() {
    $.ajax(function() {

        //do stuff here


    })
    .done(checkAjaxFinished)
    .fail(checkAjaxFinished);
}

function checkAjaxFinished(){
    ajaxCounter++;
    if(ajaxCounter==totalCount){
        alert('this is an alert at the end');
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, as someone else pointed out you should probably uses classes instead of IDs as IDs are supposed to be unique. However, I went with what you were doing for the answer.

Comment: What I don't like about this answer is that it does not account for one of the requests possibly failing.

Comment: Is it possible to handle a situation where one of the calls blow up?

Comment: `$.when()` is a utility to wrap many promises/deferreds into a new promise that resolves when they all finish and rejects when one or more fail.  To use an array of deferreds, you have to use `$.when.apply(null, promiseArray);` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: @GeorgeNewton updated code using the fail method to increment the count on success or failure. IF you wanted you could call separate methods and have a failed and succeed counter and alert the user.

Here is the doc on it... http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: If in that case, you can use `always`

Comment: Also, what I meant about not catching failures had to do with his application logic.  I would expect if one failed, he would want to do something different.  Or if he wanted to track progress or whatever...  This method makes it harder to track without adding more and more mutable state / global vars.

Comment: Thank you Lenny, I just tested it and it worked out fine. You are a Norse god! In accordance with the Stackoverflow Social Exchange policy I will upvote your post by 1 and accept your answer as the best of the best!

Answer (score 0):

`ID`s must be unique.

Use class instead.

Also, `ajax` calls will not work in loop. Better way to handle is to use recursive function.

Try:

Assuming you have classes called `test`.

```
var len = $('.test').length;
call_ajax(0);
function call_ajax(i){
    $.ajax(function() {...})
    .complete(function {
        if(i < len){
            call_ajax(i+1); //recursive call
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think someone is downvoting all but one...?  Have an upvote

Answer (score -1):

Yea like Lenny said, your code is executing just fine.

```
$('#test').each(function() {
    ...
}).promise().done(function () {alert("This is an alert");});
```

will setup all your ajax calls to run but not wait for each call to complete. Thats why the alert is happening before the calls complete. your promise object is on the each loop not the ajax calls. If you add a `promise().done()/complete()` to each of the ajax calls and count how many of them are complete you can know when all of them are done.